# Unable to mount secret to Dockerfile using docker build/push action on GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, github-actions, docker-build

I am trying to leverage the `secrets` passing functionality in a docker build-push process using the corresponding [action](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/secrets/).

Here is how I am invoking the action

```
     - name: build and push base runtime image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          file: path/to/Dockerfile 
          build-args: |
            USERNAME=${{ inputs.username }}
          secrets: |
            ${{ secrets.MY_PASSWORD }}
```

The `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ARG USERNAME

COPY ./test-script.sh .

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=MY_PASSWORD \
  cat /run/secrets/MY_PASSWORD

RUN ./test-script.sh ${USERNAME} $(cat /run/secrets/MY_PASSWORD)
```

The build process fails with:

```
cat: /run/secrets/MY_PASSWORD: No such file or directory
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. you do not pass the secret correctly to the action - you'll have to use  `"MY_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.MY_PASSWORD }}"`
2. You need to mount the secret on each `RUN` statement that you will try to use it.

Here are your fixed files:

the pipeline snippet

```yaml
     - name: build and push base runtime image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          file: path/to/Dockerfile 
          build-args: |
            USERNAME=${{ inputs.username }}
          secrets: |
            "MY_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.MY_PASSWORD }}"
```

and the Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ARG USERNAME

COPY ./test-script.sh .

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=MY_PASSWORD \
  cat /run/secrets/MY_PASSWORD

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=MY_PASSWORD \
  ./test-script.sh ${USERNAME} $(cat /run/secrets/MY_PASSWORD)
```